# grails spring security ui password validator

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am wanting to validate a password in my own controller.
Is there any way I can sent the password to spring security UI and get a return if the password validates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
springSecurityService.encodePassword
```

If you have configured your system with salt you will need that as well.  Just encode the String, and read the encoded String from your user object, and compare the two

Docs:

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService

Comment: I'm wanting to validate it so it requires 8 digits at least one letter, one number and one special character. Im hoping i can use the validate command to do this